# How does DirectX 3 (Three) present information to the display?

Tags: c++, dll, directx, hook, directdraw

I have aquired a proxyDLL for DirectDraw, but none of the proxied functions get called, but the game works with the proxyDLL.

Somehow FRAPS is able to show the frames per second counter, so it know how the data is displayed.

But none of the functions I suspect which update the display actually get hit. Breakpoints don't seem to be hit. Ever. (I tried Flip, Begin/EndScene, etc)

The code I got it from is this link:

http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/lightningstools/trunk/D3D_DDraw_Proxy/

So my question is:

Which functions does DirectX 3 use to update the display?
Which functions do I need to look for / place a breakpoint?

The problem here is that I am unable to find any documentation for DirectX 3.

I checked with processexplorer to see if D3D9 dll's are loaded, but none are. So D3D9 hooking is not an option.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a DX3. My first encounter was with DX5. And that was in '97! This is what legacy stands for... :)

Comment: Oh my! Check abandonware sites like [this](http://vetusware.com/) if you can to find SDK with docs.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean Direct-3D, rather than Direct-X 3?

Comment: the readme of the game really states the game requires Direct X 3.0+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From the link you provided, it's DX 7 not DX 3, DirectDraw was merged to Direct3D from DirectX 8, so the one who want to use DDraw always choose DX 7. notice file name on the page. myID3D7.cpp  myID3D7.h  myID3DDevice7.cpp  myID3DDevice7.h
- How did you use the proxy dll?
- Make sure the game really require the DirectX runtime. and which version does it need, you can check this by [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).